# In a Go case statement featuring channels, where does the blocking happen?

Tags: go, syntax

I am a Go rookie.

I'm looking at this construct:

```
for {
    select {
        case <-resyncCh:
        case <-stopCh:
            return
        case <-cancelCh:
            return
    }
    if r.ShouldResync == nil || r.ShouldResync() {
        // do stuff
    }
    resyncCh = r.resyncChan()
}
```

- I understand that the `for` loop runs forever.
- I understand that `break` is implicit in Go.
- I [understand that channel operations in a `select` statement are blocking if there's no `default` clause](https://gobyexample.com/select) (which there isn't here).

Suppose `resyncCh` does not have a message on it.

Are *all* the `case`s evaluated (blocked on) in parallel?  Or is there another path through this I'm not seeing?

I read this as:

- Block on the `resyncCh`, the `stopCh` and the `cancelCh` `chan`s in parallel waiting for messages
- If a message is received on `resyncCh`, we effectively fall through to the `r.ShouldResync` stuff, but the other blocks on the other `chan`s remain.
- If a message is received at any point on either the `stopCh` or the `cancelCh` `chan`, return, effectively "disconnecting" from all `chan`s here.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In direct answer to your questions:

- Block on the resyncCh, the stopCh and the cancelCh chans in parallel waiting for messages. YES.
- If a message is received on resyncCh, we effectively fall through to the r.ShouldResync stuff, but the other blocks on the other chans remain. *No*, they don't remain, you are past the `select` However, since this loops, you will block again. You could also use the `fallthrough` keyword to make them block after passing the initial one.
- If a message is received at any point on either the stopCh or the cancelCh chan, return, effectively "disconnecting" from all chans here. *Correct* - they would return from this function.

Also, bear in mind what you can do with a `default` --> https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations

```
for {
    select {
        case <-resyncCh:
        case <-stopCh:
            return
        case <-cancelCh:
            return
        default:
            fmt.Printf("will keep printing\n")
    }
    if r.ShouldResync == nil || r.ShouldResync() {
        // do stuff
    }
    resyncCh = r.resyncChan()
}
```

update: Another useful pattern, I'm using right now, which takes advantage of this:

```
select {
case m := <-c:
        handle(m)
case <-time.After(5 * time.Minute):
        fmt.Println("timed out")
}
```

Here you can wait, blocking, on a channel, but eventually timeout, just using the golang `time` package. Very succinct and easy to read. Compare that to `poll()` with `timespec` values.
https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After

Comment: Also also, bear in mind that all the cases are evaluated each execution of the `select`, regardless of which (if any) is executed; for example, if you have a function call in a `case` condition, *it will be executed regardless of whether that case is selected*. This has tripped me up before.

Comment: @Adrian: you mean the expression that determines whether the given `case` is "true"?  That's interesting, so it looks like `case` evaluation is in parallel, then, regardless?

Comment: It's not in parallel, it's sequential. See [the explanation of `select` in the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements).

Comment: Useful: somehow glossed over that a `select` statement is different from a `switch` statement.  Got it now.

Comment: Worth noting, it evaluates any calls and side effects of the case statement themselves (for example, if you had `case <-foo()`, then `foo()` would be called, but the channel receive wouldn't yet happen), in sequence, until all have been evaluated.  Only _then_ does it check if any of the channel operations can be completed, and if more than one can, _one is selected at random_.  So evaluation is sequential, but which case is selected, if multiple are available, is random and unrelated to case order.

Comment: @Kaedys: Thank you! Related question: elsewhere in the code `resyncCh` _can_ be set to a channel on which nothing will ever be sent.  If we presume for the thought experiment that nothing will be sent on either the `stopCh` or the `cancelCh` as well, then this `select` statement will block forever, doing nothing, yes?

Comment: Correct.  Also note that receives from (and sends to) `nil` channels block forever regardless.  That said, note that you don't always have to _send_ on a channel for a receive to succeed.  Receives from closed channels always succeed immediately (and give you the zero value for the type of the channel, if there's nothing in the channel's buffer).

Comment: And as per comment above, if not obvious, calling `close()` on a channel will unblock in `select`

Answer (score 1):

`select` takes first not blocked action and goes to next operation.

> Block on the resyncCh, the stopCh and the cancelCh chans in parallel waiting for messages

Yes, waiting for first of them.

> If a message is received on resyncCh, we effectively fall through to the r.ShouldResync stuff, but the other blocks on the other chans remain.

Unlike in some other languages fallthrough is explicit in go - you should state it.

> If a message is received at any point on either the stopCh or the cancelCh chan, return, effectively "disconnecting" from all chans here.

Exit from the function where the code located. Yes, we do not wait for new messages more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Regarding the (lack of) fallthrough, this is Kubernetes source code, not mine.  It looks like they're using an empty `case` body to effectively exit the `select` statement, right?

Comment: Yes.  That's an implicit `break`, though, not a `fallthrough`.  `fallthrough` tells it to continue into the next following case, not to exit the `select` and continue with the code below it.  `break` is implicit, `fallthrough` is not (which is the inverse of C++).

Comment: And I think the fundamental that you're looking for here is, once a case is selected in a `select` statement, the other cases _are abandoned_ until that select statement is called again (if in a loop).  If one succeeds, the others stop receiving and execution proceeds only according to that case.